# Refreshing the Excel Addin List

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-addins

I am trying to check with VBA if an Excel Addin is installed. However, the Addins list (Application.AddIns) remains empty unless I go into the Excel interface and list the Addins, then Application.Addins will populate with all the addins.

I tried using "Application.VBE.AddIns.Update" and "Excel.Application.COMAddIns.Update"
but I get the same results.

Using Windows 10, Excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

The AddIns are a collection. Try to view them like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim cnt         As Long
    For cnt = 1 To AddIns.Count
        Debug.Print AddIns(cnt).Name
        Debug.Print AddIns(cnt).Installed
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

Then you will see what you get. This is the standard:

```
ANALYS32.XLL
True
ATPVBAEN.XLAM
False
SOLVER.XLAM
True
```

Comment: When I try that, it will not even go into the loop, as the Addins collection is empty. However, there are certainly addins installed. I also noticed that if I pause execution using the debugger, that will also cause the Addins collection to populate.

Comment: @user3397513 - can you try to record a macro, doing exactly what you do manually in Excel *"I go into the Excel interface and list the Addins"*, when the addins appear?

Comment: When I record a macro, nothing shows up in VBA - I guess since listing the addins takes place in the Excel app, not in a worksheet. The steps I took are Office Button -> Excel Options -> Addins

Answer (score 0):

Office differentiates between add-ins and COM add-ins. They exist in separate collections. To enumerate you COM add-ins, do the following:

```
Dim ai As COMAddIn
For Each ai in Application.COMAddIns
    Debug.Print ai.Description
Next ai
```